# Breaking javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event

```
$('#ship_Move').click(function (event) {                
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.shipActionsList').remove();
        moveShip(shpID);
    });
```

that calls a function moveShip

```
function moveShip(shp_id) {
    $('.fieldDivs').click(function () {       
        $("#hello").append("Move "+ shp_id + "to " + $(this).attr('id')+"<br/>");
    });
}
```

And the debugging is giving the right results - but with one problem. If I first click the #ship_Move element 4 times, and then select a destination (.fieldDivs) I get this:

Move 162 to FD455

Move 162 to FD455

Move 162 to FD455

Move 162 to FD455

Because the moveShip function has been called 4 times, and each of them are waiting for a .fieldDivs element to be clicked, and when it is clicked, all 4 of them append their results (162 is the ship ID I want to move, FD455 is its destination).

What I need is something among these lines:

```
function moveShip(shp_id) {
    $('.fieldDivs').click(function () {       
        $("#hello").append("Move "+ shp_id + "to " + $(this).attr('id')+"<br/>");
        // IF A NEW #SHIP_MOVE IS CLICKED, END THIS FUNCTION AS IT WILL BE CALLED AGAIN
    });
}
```

I know I can return false to break functions, but for a click event I need a new function, so return false would just end the click event inside that event. What I mean is - if you exchange the above commented line //IF A NEW SHIP with the following code:

```
 $('.ship_Move').click(function () {       
         //   return false would break this function
        });
```

This code will only end this click event, but not the moveShip function.

I hope I made myself clear enough... 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try entering the Konami code to see what happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could unbind existing `click` event handler beforehand:

```
$('.fieldDivs').off('click').click(function() {
   // ...
});
```

If there are other `click` event handlers that should be kept, I suggest to use *namespaced events*:

```
$('.fieldDivs').off('click.move').on('click.move', funciton() {
   // ...
});
```

---

Though, after thinking about it, instead of binding event handlers over and over again, you could just bind them once and share necessary data via variables:

```
$(function() {
   var shpID = ...; // however this is set

    $('#ship_Move').click(function (event) {                
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.shipActionsList').remove();
        // set shpID here somehow?
    });

    $('.fieldDivs').click(function () {       
        $("#hello").append("Move "+ shpID + "to " + $(this).attr('id')+"<br/>");
    });
});
```

It doesn't look like you have to bind a new event handler only because `shpID` changes. Of course this is a simplified example since I don't know your code, but maybe it helps.